# how do i pass a list of variable values to a SQL statement in a postgres dblink function?

Tags: postgresql, grafana, dblink, grafana-variable

i have a multivalue variable called countries.  i am forced to deal with multiple postgres databases in a monitoring situation so i need to use a dblink to generate a table alias.  how do i call the below function passing the countries in the IN clause?

```
dblink(
 'link1',
 'select * from table where country_id in (' || ${countries} || ')'
) as (
  col1 text,
 col2 text etc...
)
```

the variable is passed early and results in

```
dblink(
 'link1',
 'select * from table where country_id in (' || 'IN','CN' || ')'
) as (
  col1 text,
 col2 text etc...
)
```

this results in

```
dblink(
 'link1',
 'select * from table where country_id in (IN',
 'CN)'
) as (
  col1 text,
 col2 text etc...
)
```

which is basically wrong number of arguments being passed to dblink() and more importantly a nonsensical query.  i could not figure out a way of wrapping the variable value in a set of quotes.. so that dblink would not parse the comma.

Any suggestions?

I tried using replace function to escape single quotes.  tried using the grafana join() function to concatenate countries with '','' etc.  all suggestions from chatgpt.

EDIT: For now i have solved this problem by using a numeric field. I luckily had the option of joining an addition table to use a numeric field. the reason i picked this option is because ${countries.csv} was rightly producing IN,CN so i changed it to country_id so that i ended up with 1,2 instead which doesnt have to deal with quotes. here is the final solution that works.

```
dblink(
 'link1',
 'select * from table where country_id_pk in (' || '${countries:csv}' || ')'
) as (
  col1 text,
 col2 text etc...
)
```

Comment: A comparrison between tables in 2 databases is as far as i know not possible with a dblink. It just retrieves data absed on a query. Any mention of a parameter will result in the parameter being looked up on the external db, instead of the current db. Also foreign data wrapper might be better here? you can then just join the tables.